# Font awesome content not showing up when defined inside sass

Tags: html, css, sass

So for whatever reason, I'm unable to make my font awesome content items work inside my `.sass` files and I've tried every option in the book.

Here is the `wp_register_script` so that the Font Awesome is called inside WP:

```
wp_register_script(
    'font-awesome',
    'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/js/all.js',
    [],
    '5.14.0',
    true
);
```

Shows up in the `footer` as the following:
[image]

Then here is where I have my `&:after` psuedo call:

```
&:after
  content: "\f105"
  position: absolute
  right: 30px
  transition: all 0.5s
  font-weight: 900
  font-style: normal
```

This is the result that I'm getting:
[image]

All that I'm getting rendered inside the `console` and on the actual website is just a black box, I want to be able to display the `>` arrow.

All help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specifiy the font-family for the :after pseudo-element and also maybe - display: block or display: inline-block to allow it to render ...

And also - since you are setting this to be position: absolute - - you will need to set its parent element to be position: relative to allow the correct positioning....

```
   .menu-list s span { 
     position: relative; // added this - to allow absolute poisitioning of the icon within the span.
   } 

&:after {
  content: "\f105",
  position: absolute,
  right: 30px,
  transition: all 0.5s,
  font-weight: 900,
  font-style: normal,
  font-family: FontAwesome, // added this line
  display: block, // added this line
  ...
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much gavgrif.

Comment: No probs - Glad I could help - happy coding :)